# Rails class name/type not working for a polymorphic has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, polymorphic-associations, has-many-through

I have an invoicing system that manages debits and credits. Basically the invoice amount is obtained by the sum of its debits and the balance is derived by taking the sum of its credits and subtracting it against the total amount.

I'm doing this with four models.

1. Invoice
2. Line Item
3. Debit
4. Credit

The way it works is via a join model (Line Item) that has a polymorphic association called recordable. Everything appears to work properly at first glance. **However, inspecting the line item shows that while the recordable_id shows up alright, the recordable_type is nil.**

Here is a break down of the code:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :debits, :through => :line_items, :as => :recordable
  has_many :credits, :through => :line_items, :as => :recordable
end

class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice
  belongs_to :recordable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :credit, :class_name => "Credit", :foreign_key => "recordable_id"
  belongs_to :debit,  :class_name => "Debit",   :foreign_key => "recordable_id"
end

class Credit < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, :as => :recordable, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Debit < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, :as => :recordable, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Can anyone point me into the right direction here?

Comment: How do you assign line_items to Credit/Debit?

Comment: This happens automatically via the has_many :through. So when you do Invoice.last.credits << Credit.new the LineItem is automatically generated and built with the right recordable_id and invoice_id.

Comment: Shouldn't the `:as` be on `has_many :line_items`, not the `has_many :through` associations?

Comment: No because invoice_id is a field on the line_item object. The polymorphism is only for the debit and credit objects which do use :as on their :has_many declarations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring ambigous associations on your `LineItem` class.

In a nutshell, `belongs_to` does this in your class:

1. `belongs_to :invoice` creates a method `invoice` which searches the *invoices* table for a record referenced by `invoice_id`
2. `belongs_to :recordable, :polymorphic => true` creates a method `recordable` which searches the `recordable_type.underscore.pluralize` table for a record referenced by `recordable_id`
3. `belongs_to :credit, :class_name => "Credit", :foreign_key => "recordable_id"` creates a method `credit` which searches through the *credits* table for a record referenced by `recordable_id`. Note, that `recordable_type` is ignored here.
4. same applies to `belongs_to :debit` respectively.

Since your LineItem may only belong to either a Credit **or** a Debit it makes no sense to declare these associations additionally. You can refer to these via the `recordable` association.

Answer (score 0):

Invoice.last.credits << Credit.new

This is the correct way in assigning associations to I am stumped as to why the `recordable_type` is not being picked up.

Clutching at straws here but have you tried:

```
Invoice.last.credits << Credit.create(:value => 1, :date => Time.now, ...)
```

I've personally had issues when using multi-type many-to-many join tables in Rails, which was often resolved by using the [`has_many_polymorphs`](http://github.com/fauna/has_many_polymorphs) plugin.

Sorry that this  does not directly answer your question.

Comment: Yeah I ended up just creating a direct relationship as the behavior of the application no longer needed the many to many relationship of invoices to debits. I'm not sure why it's not picking it up either though. I have done the same exact setup for different objects in the past. Maybe I've stumbled onto a protected name but I can't think of it. Originally I was using item_id and item_type but even after changing to recordable_id and type it still didn't work. Completely stumped.